# Github data in transit

Tags: github, encryption, source-code-protection, transit

I was just wondering how the data is encrypted during transit to Github. Checking online there seems to be information about the encryption of the source code at rest but I can't seem to find any info on encryption during transit.

From Github blog:
"Source code stored on GitHub.com will be encrypted at rest, by default. Any source code previously stored on GitHub.com has been converted over to hosts with encrypted disks. For GitHub Enterprise Server customers, encryption at rest is dependent on the host in which Enterprise Server is running, not a function of the Server software itself."

Thanks

Couldn't find any information on Google about my question.

Comment: Didn't you notice that all your browsing and reading on github is done via https? It's all secured by TLS/SSL.

Comment: Yeah I know Github the site itself is encrypted and the data at rest. But I was referring to Git as a protocol but I understand that the data is encrypted whilst in transit also.